# Add filter by custom field to block of posts

Tags: posts, filters

I need to put a block on a page that displays 'highlighted posts' manually.

First of all, I do not know if there is a better way to do this, creating a new block, or using an existing plugin ...
(Maybe I should clone one of these blocks and add the functionality for my case but I'm not sure)

The idea that I have is to be able to use an existing block, for example: 'List of posts' exiting in the 'Gutenberg' editor, or the 'Grid of posts' in the 'Ultimate Addons for Gutenberg' plugin, which I have installed in my WP. and then, adding a new field to it in order to filter the posts.

For this I have added a new field to the posts called 'highlight_in'. which could take values like ('home.top', 'home.moreviews', 'shop.moreviews'...)

My question is that **I do not know how to add a new filter for 'highlight_in' field in a block of post I commented before**.

NOTE: I should also make a 'SELECT posts WHERE highlight_in LIKE %filter_value%' query to be able to highlight the post in more than one page / block.

I do not know if there are here too many things for a question. So If necessary, I modify or divide the content of this question.
Thanks.